# how to delete all nodes in the list

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

```
public void deleteAll() {
    if(head==null) {
        System.out.println("list already empty");
    }
    else {
        Node temp=head; Node del;
        while(temp.next!=null) {
            del=temp.next;
            temp=null;
            temp=del;
        }
        System.out.println("all nodes deleted");
    }
}
```

this is  the method to delete all nodes in linked list without taking parameters.

Comment: The previous' node `next` will still point to `temp`

Comment: `temp=null` only affects `temp`. It doesn't affect whatever variable `temp` was assigned from.

Comment: Also `temp=null` doesn't work as java is *pass-by-value* and not *pass-by-reference*

Comment: so instead of temp= null what can I write to delete the previous node.

Comment: @SubhamPadhihary `head = null` is simply enough

Comment: @Lino yeah it does but I want to delete each node individually just for the sake of it. So how do I do that?

Comment: @RedViper You can use this simple bodyless for-loop: `for(; head != null; head = head.next);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void deleteAll() {
    head = null;
}
```

You forgot to set `head` to null.

And because of garbage collections all nodes of the list are no longer referencable and will be garbage collected.

Setting a variable to null will have no real effect. Setting a field to null, will make the object (value) probably inaccessible and free for garbage collection.

Comment: well that worked. But say I want to manually delete each node in the list. how do i do that?

Comment: The first element could be removed by `if (head != null) head = head.next;`. Change the `if` into a `while` and you continue removing elements. However immediately setting `head` to null has the same effect.

Comment: In java there is no `delete` operator / `free` function, so one has to rely on the jvm.